# can I customize selected visuals within a PBI report for users to export into PDF or PowerPoint?

Tags: powerbi

I understand Power BI portal service users can export a PBI report into PDF or Powerpoint using the "Export to PDF/PowerPoint" feature, and users could include/exclude hidden pages in the output.
Questions:
(1) Instead of allowing users to export everything, I am hoping to define and customize the PDF/PowerPoint output to only a few selected visuals in a preset sequence/format.  Is this possible?  If yes, how?
(2)  If the above is feasible, then can I turn off the default "Export to PDF/PowerPoint" feature for that specific report?    Or at least disable users the ability to export the hidden pages.

Appreciate knowledge sharing, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, you can control this only on a tenant level, and not on individual report/workspace level. An admin can go to the `Admin portal` -> `Tenant settings`, and in `Export and sharing settings` to disable `Export reports as PowerPoint presentations or PDF documents` section:

[image]

For more information, take a look at [Administering Power BI in the admin portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-portal#export-reports-as-powerpoint-presentations-or-pdf-documents).

If you want, you can vote for [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Custom-Visuals-Ideas/Allow-disabling-Export-to-PDF-PPT-by-report-or-Workspace/idi-p/1732982).